# How to check the status of loadbalancer with AWS Java Elastic Load Balancer SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, amazon-elb

I have a cli command which I am trying to convert Java SDK:

```
aws elb wait any-instance-in-service --load-balancer-name $lb_name --profile $AWS_PROFILE
```

which should report that the load balancer created by EKS is running and ready.

I am using:

```
ElasticLoadBalancingV2Client
```

with gradle:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.4.4'
    }
}
    compile 'software.amazon.awssdk:elasticloadbalancingv2'
```

So far the SDK appears to provide just about anything but give the status of a load balancer.

I am investigating

```
describeLoadBalancerAttributes
```

right now, but if anyone found the needle before myself would very much appreciate the help.

I need equivalent of this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/wait/load-balancer-available.html

or this (older version I guess)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/wait/instance-in-service.html

Answer (score 0):

I found it on the very link I posted :facepalm:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLoadBalancers.html

Will add details later when will have the code(or you can beat me to that) and I will accept your answer instead. Thanks.